# Which are the TTextFormat(s) values (used in TextRect) and their meanings?

Tags: delphi, text-formatting

I want to apply some text formats in `TextRect` procedure but I don't found any documentation. In Delphi help, at [`TextRect`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Graphics_TCanvas_TextRect@TRect@Integer@Integer@string.html) reference, says that TextFormat variabile can have only 3 values: [`tfAutoText, tfText, tfPlainText`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Graphics_TTextFormat.html). But here on StackOverflow I found some `TextRect` examples with other text format values, like `tfEndEllipsis`. I've searched this on Delphi help and I found [other set](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Graphics_TTextFormats.html) with many text format values. When I tried them, the first set with those 3 values doesn't work at all, but the second set works. I'm confused. Which set is the good one ? It seems the second one is, because it's working. But then, what is the first set for ?

And what is the meaning of the following values (from the second set) ? :

- tfCalcRect
- tfEditControl
- tfExpandTabs
- tfExternalLeading
- tfModifyString
- tfNoClip
- tfNoPrefix
- tfRtlReading
- tfWordBreak

The others are obvious...

Comment: Just to clarify the answer, the set of tfAutoText, tfText, tfPlainText does not exist, and if it did would be assignment-incompatible with the real TTextFormat - it's a completely different type. It's not present anywhere in the VCL source - I searched the entire thing. I edited the docwiki talk page to request a fix. Basically, ignore it, and use the second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Graphics.TTextFormat) is wrong. The three enumerated type values listed there (`tfAutoText`, `tfText`, `tfPlainText`) do not exist.

You need to read the source of the `Vcl.Graphics` unit to get to the bottom of this. The source looks like this:

```
type
  TTextFormats = (tfBottom, tfCalcRect, tfCenter, tfEditControl, tfEndEllipsis,
    tfPathEllipsis, tfExpandTabs, tfExternalLeading, tfLeft, tfModifyString,
    tfNoClip, tfNoPrefix, tfRight, tfRtlReading, tfSingleLine, tfTop,
    tfVerticalCenter, tfWordBreak, tfHidePrefix, tfNoFullWidthCharBreak,
    tfPrefixOnly, tfTabStop, tfWordEllipsis, tfComposited);
  TTextFormat = set of TTextFormats;
```

And these values map directly onto the flags used by the Win32 API function [`DrawTextEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162499.aspx). You can find out what they mean by reading the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162499.aspx) for that function.

Comment: The `tfComposited` flag is exceptional and cannot be used with `TCanvas.TextRect` method. It doesn't map to a formatting option of the `DrawTextEx` function, but is internally mapped to the `DTT_COMPOSITED` option of the `DrawThemeTextEx` function.

Comment: Does this mean that  `TTextFormat TF = TTextFormat() << TTextFormats(DT_HIDEPREFIX)` is supposed to work ?  Or is my interpretation of 'mapping onto' too simple in this context ? PS. It doesn't seem to work on my old C++ Builder 2009 where `tfHidePrefix` appears to be unknown, and I need it in a custom paint event.